# Angular5 jQuery Directive - UI undefined during import

Tags: jquery, angular, directive

I am using Angular 5, jQuery 3.3.1.

I want to use the jQuery ui.dialog function. I use the SmartAdmin template, which comes with directives that incorporate various jQuery functions. I use several of the jQuery directives without problem. But, this is my first attempt at using the ui directives. When I import the ui directives module (named JqueryUiModule) into my component module, I get a  error `Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined
    at Object../src/app/shared/ui/jquery-ui/jqui-dialog/jqui-dialog.directive.ts`.

I show some of the directive below, but the complaint is about ui being undefined `$.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype`.

At this point, I am not trying to use the directive, I'm only trying to import it.

**component module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { jqueryUiRouting } from './jquery-ui.routing';
import { JqueryUiComponent } from "./jquery-ui.component";
import { SmartadminModule } from "../../shared/smartadmin.module";
import { JqueryUiModule } from "../../shared/ui/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    jqueryUiRouting,
    SmartadminModule,

    JqueryUiModule,
  ],
  declarations: [JqueryUiComponent]
})
export class JqueryUiShowcaseModule { }
```

**JqueryUiModule:**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {JquiDialogLauncher} from "./jqui-dialog/jqui-dialog-launcher.directive";
import {JquiAccordion} from "./jqui-accordion.directive";
import {JquiMenu} from "./jqui-menu.directive";
import {JquiAutocomplete} from "./jqui-autocomplete.directive";
import {JquiProgressbar} from "./jqui-progressbar.directive";
import {JquiSpinner} from "./jqui-spinner.directive";
import {JquiSlider} from "./jqui-slider.directive";
import {JquiTabs} from "./jqui-tabs.directive";
import {JquiDialog} from "./jqui-dialog/jqui-dialog.directive";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    JquiDialog,
    JquiDialogLauncher,
    JquiAccordion,
    JquiMenu,
    JquiAutocomplete,
    JquiProgressbar,
    JquiSpinner,
    JquiSlider,
    JquiTabs,
  ],
  exports: [
    JquiDialog,
    JquiDialogLauncher,
    JquiAccordion,
    JquiMenu,
    JquiAutocomplete,
    JquiProgressbar,
    JquiSpinner,
    JquiSlider,
    JquiTabs,
  ]
})
export class JqueryUiModule {
}
```

**JquiDialog - directive having problem:**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;


$.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
  _title: function(title) {
    if (!this.options.title ) {
      title.html("&#160;");
    } else {
      title.html(this.options.title);
    }
  }
}));

@Directive({
  selector: '[saJquiDialog]'
})
export class JquiDialog implements OnInit {


  @Input() saJquiDialog: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }


  ngOnInit(){

    $(this.el.nativeElement).dialog(this.saJquiDialog)
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping! Bob

Comment: try adding $(this.el.nativeElement).dialog(this.saJquiDialog) under ngAfterViewInit()  instead of ngOnInit()

Comment: I tried it Suresh, but no fix. It does seem like an initialization issue, though. The SmartAdmin demo uses same code, and works. What I've been looking for is some jQuery UI init that would take place in something like typings.d.ts, but am not seeing anything related.

Comment: Problem Solved. It was due to: `lib.ts(18): // import 'jquery-ui-npm/jquery-ui.min.js'`. Uncommenting the import solved it.